# C# autoanalysing on VirusTotal

Tags: c#

Good afternoon!

I need analyse file on VirusTotal and then save detection number in some variable but I am lost. I tried this code: https://github.com/Genbox/VirusTotal.NET but everytime I run it shows me a message that I don't have entered API key which is not true. I tried to put it everywhere.

Do you have any experience with this problem? Or do you have another solution?

Thank you very much!
Regards,
Aleš

//edit:
VirusTotal.NET Client

```
 namespace VirusTotalNETClient
    {
        class Program
        {
            private const string ScanUrl = "http://www.google.com/";

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                VirusTotal virusTotal = new VirusTotal(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"]);

                //Use HTTPS instead of HTTP
                virusTotal.UseTLS = true;

                //Create the EICAR test virus. See http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("EICAR.txt");
                File.WriteAllText(fileInfo.FullName, @"X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*");

                //Check if the file has been scanned before.
                FileReport fileReport = virusTotal.GetFileReport(fileInfo);

                bool hasFileBeenScannedBefore = fileReport.ResponseCode == ReportResponseCode.Present;

                Console.WriteLine("File has been scanned before: " + (hasFileBeenScannedBefore ? "Yes" : "No"));

                //If the file has been scanned before, the results are embedded inside the report.
                if (hasFileBeenScannedBefore)
                {
                    PrintScan(fileReport);
                }
                else
                {
                    ScanResult fileResult = virusTotal.ScanFile(fileInfo);
                    PrintScan(fileResult);
                }
```

VirusTotal.NET

```
namespace VirusTotalNET
{
    public partial class VirusTotal
    {
        private readonly RestClient _client = new RestClient();
        private readonly string _apiKey;
        private bool _useTls;

        /// <summary>
        /// Public constructor for VirusTotal.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="apiKey">5d8684f50946c2bdeaf5c4fd966f61f3661de808e9d7324b99788d6f4fb7ad57</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
        public VirusTotal(string apiKey)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey) || apiKey.Length < 64)
                throw new ArgumentException("You have to set an API key.", "apiKey");

            ApiUrl = "www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/";
            _useTls = true;
            _apiKey = apiKey;
            _client.FollowRedirects = false;

            FileSizeLimit = 33553369; //32 MB - 1063 = 33553369 it is the effective limit by virus total
            RestrictSizeLimits = true;
            RestrictNumberOfResources = true;
        }
```

Comment: *"I tried to put it everywhere..."*.... Well, at least you could show some of your code, so someone could point you to the right direction.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: I edited my previous post so now you can see there both important parts of code... do you have any idea where I should put that API key? Thank you!

Comment: @AlešWilk you put your API key in `AppSettings["ApiKey"])`

Comment: @Kritner I tried it also... :/ http://upnisito.cz/images/2016_12/550virustotal.png this is what happens.

Comment: that screenshot does not help, or prove the above statement you just made.    If the code in the question is your actual code, then you are not properly setting up your appsettings.

Comment: and i'm not sure if "5d8684f50946c2bdeaf5c4fd966f61f3661de808e9d7324b99788d6f4fb7ad57" is your API key or not, you have it in the XML documentation, which is only comments and not actually compiled.  Hopefully this is not your actual API key, and not already in use on production, or you may need to get a new one as it is now "out there"

Comment: @Kritner: I solved this problem already... instead of `VirusTotal virusTotal = new VirusTotal(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"]);` I used `VirusTotal virusTotal = new VirusTotal("ApiKey");`